# Could we make spring-lemon available in maven public repository?

Tags: spring-lemon

I'm trying to deploy a spring-lemon app from github. 
But the way [the documentation](https://www.gitbook.com/book/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon-getting-started) advised to obtain and install the jar, isn't working. 
While I keep on trying to sort this out, I wonder if it's possible to make spring-lemon available in maven public repo ?
That would be the perfect way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree, and would like to see it in the central maven repository in fact. But, it needs some preparation to get approved. Sometime back I had tried it with some other project, but couldn't get approved.

So, it's low in my priority list now. Could you please create a ticket in GitHub, and it would be great if someone volunteers to take up this before I can.

**Update 2021-08-21**: 1.0.0.RC6 onward available on maven central

Comment: How about using some private repo like myMavenRepo.com ?

Comment: Yes, that wouldn't need us any approval. Although I had done that for a past project, I don't remember the exact procedure. If you want you could try that out, and let me know if you need write access to the repository. Or, you could create a ticket, and I'll look when I'll get some time. Currently I'm too busy onto many things, and don't hope to find some time anytime soon.

Comment: I'm still struggling with this issue. Even when I install maven on my production server, that doesn't seem to solve it.    I finally decided to merge Spring Lemon's source code with my project. Any advice on how to properly do that ?

Comment: First, I don't know why the currently suggested setup (i.e. checking out Spring Lemon in your workspace) should be a problem for deploying your application to a cloud service or a server. Maybe you're doing something wrong? Secondly, hosting a repository should be easy. Maybe this can help -> http://ediweissmann.com/blog/2013/07/11/free-private-maven-repository-hosting/ . Let me know if you don't succeed; I'll give a try if it can be done quickly. Merging the source code will need manually placing the files in your project, I think. But then won't you lose the benefit of new updates, etc.?

Comment: Did you get some solution, Moise? I am curious how deploying could be an issue with the currently suggested setup.